# problem implementing ele if statement using ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement else-if statement using terenary operator but i am unable to get desired result. please let me know how can i achive my desired output.

```
let arr1 = [{t: 10},{f0: 20},{c0: 20}, {f1: 40}, {c1: 20},  {f2: 20},{c2: 20}];
let arr2 = arr1.map(v => {
    let test = Object.keys(v)[0];
    test1 = test.replace(/\d+$/, "");
    let testtest = test1 === 't' ? 'error' : (('f') ? 'fine' : 'notfine');
    return {test1, testtest};
});
console.log(arr2);
```

my desired output should be like

```
[{
  test1: "t",
  testtest: "error"
}, {
  test1: "f",
  testtest: "fine"
}, {
  test1: "c",
  testtest: "notfine"
}, 
 {
  test1: "f",
  testtest: "fine"
}, {
  test1: "c",
  testtest: "notfine"
},
 {
  test1: "f",
  testtest: "fine"
}, {
  test1: "c",
  testtest: "notfine"
}]
```

Comment: `('f') ? 'fine' : 'notfine'` is equivalent to `'fine'`. You probably meant `test1 === 'f' ? 'fine' : 'notfine'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare it twice:

```
let testtest = test1 === 't' ? 'error' : 
               test1 === 'f' ? 'fine' : 'notfine';
```

```js
let arr1 = [{t: 10},{f0: 20},{c0: 20}, {f1: 40}, {c1: 20},  {f2: 20},{c2: 20}];
let arr2 = arr1.map(v => {
    let test = Object.keys(v)[0];
    test1 = test.replace(/\d+$/, "");
    let testtest = test1 === 't' ? 'error' : 
                   test1 === 'f' ? 'fine' : 'notfine';
    return {test1, testtest};
});
console.log(arr2);
```